# Best practises for conditional mysql queries

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I am building a website where i need to build a mysql query based on user input, where not only the values, but also the query itself need to change.  What i have this far is a conditional if-else solution which works, but is very messy...

example:

```
public function getUsers($options){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Users"; // basic query
    if($options->getAdminsOnly()){
        $query .=" WHERE type='admin' ";
    }
    if($options->getOrderBy() !=null){
        $query .=" ORDER BY ".$options->getOrderBy();
    }
    if($options->groupBy() !=null){
        $query .=" GROUP BY ".$options->groupBy();
    }
    if($options->getLimit() !=null){
        $query .=" LIMIT ".$options->getLimit();
    }
    if($options->getOffset() !=null){
        $query .=" OFFSET ".$options->getOffset();
    }
    ....
    ....
}
```

This gets even messier in case of joins etc... Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are already a number of object-relational mapping (ORM) libraries available that will help you build an SQL query. I wouldn't re-invent the wheel, have a look:

[Good PHP ORM Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library)

Comment: Great, could you provide some example of how i might use ORM to avoid the if-else solution? thanks...

Comment: @DanielValland - It will not help with the if-else conditions but will prevent you from having to append or add on to various sections (lets say you want to add a second WHERE after what was added. Unless you do a string check with a library capable of parsing SQL you are out of luck. However - you can reduce the amount of code you use. Since your check is to see if the return string is empty, why not do the check in your options Object? `$options->getQuery()` where the getQuery function does the empty checks separately?